Error when trying to write dataframe to oracle database
I'm trying to insert data from a R dataframe into an existing Oracle database table using the dbWriteTable function from ROracle but get the following error: Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt) : ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier.
Dataframe structure (database table has exactly the same columns in the same order):
   POS_ID HIST_DATE  CUST_ID INS_ETL_DAT INS_ETL_PRG VAL_NUM  VAL_DATE VAL_CHAR
    <dbl> <date>       <dbl> <date>      <chr>          <dbl> <date>    <chr>    
 1      1 2023-12-31 123456  2024-08-21  foo          0.01     NA        NA       
 2      1 2023-12-31 5555555 2024-08-21  bar          0.0158   NA        NA       
 3      1 2023-12-31 1111111 2024-08-21  foo          0.0132   NA        NA       

Code:
library(ROracle)
library(tidyverse)

con <- ROracle::dbConnect(drv = ROracle::Oracle(), user, pwd, db)

Sys.setenv(TZ = "CEST")
Sys.setenv(ORA_SDTZ = "CEST")

dbWriteTable(
  conn = con,
  name = Id(schema = "MYSCHEMA", table = "MYTABLE"), 
  value = mydf,
  append = TRUE
  )

I suspected there might be a problem with the VAL_DATE and VAL_CHAR columns (they contain only NAs) but adding/removing them or filling in some dummy value does not change anything. Also changing the row.names parameter does not help.
I hoped to be able to see the SQL statement being generated by debugging ROracle::dbWriteTable() but debugonce(ROracle::dbWriteTable) only shows a empty debug-screen.

I figured out how to debug dbWriteTable (debugonce(ROracle:::.oci.WriteTable)) and found the problem: Id(schema="xxx", table="yyy") produces an invalid table name ending in "" which leads to the zero-length identifier error.
providing the database schema like this worked for me:
dbWriteTable(
  conn = con,
  name = "MYTABLE", 
  value = mydf,
  append = TRUE,
  schema = "MYSCHEMA"
  )

